# VM Exception when accessing mapping

Tags: ganache, mapping, struct, truffle-contract, error

I created a contract with a User struct than contains an age, a first name, and a last name. The function getUser() should return this information for an inputted address. But when I call my getUser() function on an address that has already been set, I get the error:

`Uncaught Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Also when I call my countUsers() function it returns "BN { negative: 0, words: [ 7, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }", when it should just return a "7"

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./EtherTransfer00.sol";

contract UserAttributes is EtherTransfer00 {
    struct User {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }

    constructor (address root) EtherTransfer00(root) public {}

    mapping (address => User) public users;
    address[] public userAccts;

    function setUser(address _address, uint _age, string memory _fName, string memory _lName) public {
        users[_address].age = _age;
        users[_address].fName = _fName;
        users[_address].lName = _lName;

        userAccts.push(_address);
    }

    function getUsers() view public returns(address[] memory) {
        return userAccts;
    }

    function getUser(address _address) public view returns (uint, string memory, string memory) {
        return (users[_address].age, users[_address].fName, users[_address].lName);
    } 
 

    function countUsers() public view returns (uint count) {
        return userAccts.length;
    }
```

Comment: it is aborting on `require` , look where is that statement and what does it validate

Comment: I tested the contract (after removing references to EtherTransfer00) and it works as expected. How are you testing? Are you using ganache or a private testnet? It is odd that `getUser` fails because it is a view and it does nothing. Since javascript doesn't support large integers `countUser` is returning a BN object. If it is a small number you can use `count.toNumber()`, for large numbers use `count.toString()` to read them as a string.

Comment: I'm using Ganache for testing. Do you know how I could get just the length from a BigNumber object?